# Pulling option values and keys from webpages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to pull the `option value` and `key` for each option. 
Not sure what i need to specify to pull either correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

OUTPUT im trying to obtain:

```
value = ['0', '118868', '118869', '118870', '118871', 'etc']
key = ['Choose color/size', 'US 6/EUR 38,5', 'US 6,5/EUR 39', 'etc']
```

code:

```
s = requests.session()  

response = s.get(product_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')

# option value
div = soup.find("div",{"id":"product-specifics"})
value = div['option']
print(value)

# Keys
for key in div.items() :
    print(key)
```

HTML:

```
            <div id="product-specifics" class="editor-field">

<select id="colorSizeDD">
<option value="0">Choose color/size</option>

    <option value="118868">US 6/EUR 38,5</option>


    <option value="118869">US 6,5/EUR 39</option>


    <option value="118870">US 7/EUR 40</option>


    <option value="118858">US 7,5/EUR 40,5</option>


    <option value="118859">US 8/EUR 41</option>


    <option value="118860">US 8,5/EUR 42</option>


    <option value="118861">US 9/EUR 42,5</option>


    <option value="118862">US 9,5/EUR 43</option>


    <option value="118863">US 10/EUR 44</option>


    <option value="118864">US 10,5/EUR 44,5</option>


    <option value="118865">US 11/EUR 45</option>


    <option value="118867">US 11,5/EUR 45,5</option>


    <option value="118866">US 12/EUR 46</option>


    <option value="118871">US 12,5/EUR 47</option>


    <option value="118872">US 13/EUR 47,5</option>



</select>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have found the div as shown by your line

> div = soup.find("div",{"id":"product-specifics"})

You can then get the select element using

```
select = div.find('select')
```

I then recommend to loop though all of the option elements from `select.find_all('option')` in a for loop. Inside this loop you should use `option['value']` to get the value and `option.getText()` to get the text. Then finally print the results as you requested.
Here would be the final product.

```
select = div.find('select')

value = []
key = []

for option in select.find_all('option'):
    value.append(option['value'])
    key.append(option.getText())

print ("value = " + str(value))
print ("key = " + str(key))
```